# How to get find element injected on a page using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, html-injections

There is a browser extension that modifies the page and inserts its own html code into it, I get the html code of the page being checked, but the html code injection from the extension does not get into it, although if you run the check in the browser, then there is an injection.

those. after rendering the page, the extension integrates a block inside the page:

```
<div><div class="notification"><div class="notification__close"></div> <div class="notification__logo"></div> <div class="notification__title">
  </div> <div class="notification__cta">
    Activate
  </div></div> <!----></div>
```

When trying to catch this block, puppeteer does not find it:

```
let browser = await puppeteer.launch ({
      headless: false,
      ignoreDefaultArgs: true,
      args: [
        `--load-extension = $ {path.join (dir, '/extension')},`
      ]
    });
let page = await browser.newPage ();

await page.goto ('https://site.url', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
await page.waitForSelector ('.notification__cta');
await page.click ('.notification__cta');
```

I get a dump on timeout when trying to find an item:: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 30000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout. Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 30000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error:

If you look at the html that is stored in the page, then the notification block does not get there ... Perhaps someone will have an idea how I can track html injections with a puppeteer and manipulate them?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo in your selector `'. notification__cta'`
There should be no space between the dot and the classname. Does it work when you change it to `'.notification__cta'` ?

Comment: it's a typo only on stackoverflow (when copy/paste). In code i try find without space, using `'.notification__cta'` and has same results. Element is not found. All block `notification` not included in `page`

Answer (score 0):

I think your extension is in the category of "[Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)".
At the moment they are not supported with puppeteer: see in the Docs, [Working with Chrome Extensions](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#working-with-chrome-extensions):

> NOTE It is not yet possible to test extension popups or content scripts.

Comment: may be you know can puppeteer get data from chrome extantion?

Comment: In case of extensions that are not "popups" or "content scripts" it may be possible. But you should follow the docs and add the flags they advises there, hopefully you can figure a workaround to test your extension.

Comment: solution in using query-selector-shadow-dom (https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-selector-shadow-dom)

Answer (score 0):

solution in using query-selector-shadow-dom (https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-selector-shadow-dom)

Comment: I doubt this is the real solution, probably the element you were trying to select was in the shadow DOM and you didn't realise that before. But you don't need a package like above for that. You can simply draw that JS path yourself as well, or use dev tools like that from Chrome to grab it for you. That would be a lot more efficient.